# How to use data obtained in a Java anonymous function that is inside of a method

Tags: java, methods, scope, anonymous-function, vert.x

Seems like a common issue, but I am just not sure of the solution.

I am using Vert.x with Java to call another service. I am using Vert.x's `WebClient` library. When I make the `POST` request, one of the arguments is an anonymous function. If the request succeeds, then I get my data.

The problem is getting this data outside of the anonymous function, in the rest of my method. I want my method to return the data obtained from my anonymous function. The data is in the `body` variable.

```
private JsonArray itemTypes() {
  WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(vertx);
  webCLient.post(80, "myApi.com", "/api/items")
    .sendJsonObject(new JsonObject().put("mutator", "*"), ar -> {
      if (ar.succeeded) {
        HttpResponse<JsonArray> result = ar.result();
        JsonArray body = result.body();
      } else {
        System.out.println(ar.cause().getMessage());
      }
    });
}
```

Right now, if I try to declare the `body` variable outside of the anonymous function and assign it inside (so that I can return the value), my IDE complains `Local variable body defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final`.

I essentially want to do something like this:

```
private JsonArray itemTypes() {
  JsonArray body;
  WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(vertx);
  webCLient.post(80, "myApi.com", "/api/items")
    .sendJsonObject(new JsonObject().put("mutator", "*"), ar -> {
      if (ar.succeeded) {
        HttpResponse<JsonArray> result = ar.result();
        body = result.body();
      } else {
        System.out.println(ar.cause().getMessage());
        body = new JsonArray();
      }
    });
  return body;
}
```

I've tried making the JsonArray body variable final, but that does not work. I've also tried to assign the whole `webClient.post(....)` call to a variable, but that did not work either.

How can I gain access to the `body` data outside of the anonymous function so I can return it in my method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is that WebClient appears to be completely asynchronous. This means that when you call `.sendJsonObject`, it basically sends the request and immediately returns; your code keeps running while WebClient waits for an answer.

Once a response is received, it calls the callback lambda you provided, possibly in some other thread. This may occur several seconds later and a lot of your other code may have had time to run in the meantime.

What you need is to have your main code wait for the response to be received. This could be done in several ways, one of which would be to create a `CompletableFuture<T>`, have the callback call the `.complete(theValue)` method and then have the outside code call `.get()` to wait for and receive the value.

In other words, the outside code would define and wait for the `CompletableFuture<T>` to complete, then have the `.sendJsonObject` callback complete it for you with the desired value.

Comment: Thanks for responding. How exactly do I implement this in the code that I have above?

Answer (score 1):

Could do something like this:

```
private Future<JsonArray> itemTypes() {
    Future<JsonArray> body = Future.future();
    WebClient webClient = 
    WebClient.create(vertx);
    webCLient.post(80, "myApi.com", "/api/items")
    .sendJsonObject(new  JsonObject().put("mutator", "*"), ar -> {
  if (ar.succeeded) {
    HttpResponse<JsonArray> result = ar.result();
    body.complete(result.body());
  } else {
    System.out.println(ar.cause().getMessage());
    body.fail(ar.cause());
  }
});
  return body;
}
```

Then set a handler on the returned future. You could also pass in the future with a handler instead, if you'd like:

```
private void itemTypes(Future<JsonArray> body) {
```